# exact opposite of grant

Tags: single-word-requests

Not a native speaker here.

What is the *exact* opposite of grant?

Yes, i've been to a thesaurus and a lot other antonym sites.

The word i'm looking for isn't 'refuse', 'deny', prohibit', etc. I want to know if there's a word (or more) for doing the opposite of granting, for example, someone's wishes.

Like when you do the opposite of what someone wants.

In the sentence:

**"The odds never bothered to hear our wishes, or perhaps it listened closely to them as to know what to *(word)*"**

The italics could be replaced by 'not grant', though does anyone know of a more specific word? Would 'forfeit' be fit to replace the italic?

Thank you

Comment: I don't understand what the opposite of 'grant' would be, in your example of wishes.  "I wish for a horse" -> "I will take your horse away from you"?  Or "I wish for a horse" -> "I will make it impossible for you to ever get a horse"?

Comment: @JohnFeltz Your first example represents better what I mean.

Comment: Look up 'sabotage' or 'thwart' and see if those are what you are looking for.  I'm not confident enough that I understand what you want to post those as answers...

Comment: @Calazans- Your example sentence in the question seems more like John's second option.    What's wrong with *deny*?  The King could hear your wish and decide to grant it, or *deny* it.  The "odds" could metaphorically decide to deny your wish as well.  A more active metaphor might be "stomp all over it"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In a comment, you mention that you want the opposite of **grant** to mean **to take away**.

[**Revoke**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/revoke):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1** : to annul by recalling or taking back : RESCIND • *revoke* a will

So, for example:

> I granted you three wishes, but now I revoke them.

Comment: To revoke implies that you had it and it was taken away.  A wish can be for something you never had before.   The King could hear your wish and decide to grant it, but he can't really revoke your wish.

Comment: @jim I agree, but that is the sense that the OP was specifically looking for. Look at the first two comments under the question itself.

Comment: Yeah, I think OP is a bit inconsistent in what's being asked for.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps they would ***prevent*** your wishes from coming true?  Per the Oxford Dictionaries:

> ***[prevent](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/prevent)***
>
> VERB
>
> [WITH OBJECT]
>
> 1. Keep (something) from happening or arising.
>
> *‘action must be taken to prevent further accidents’*

Alternatively, perhaps a synonym of *prevent* would work?  I like ***[thwart](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/thwart)***, but I could also see *[rule out](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/rule_something_out_(or_in))*, *[preclude](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/preclude)*, and *[forestall](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/us/forestall)* fitting.

Answer (score 1):

**Rescind**-
revoke, cancel, or repeal (a law, order, or agreement).
"the government eventually rescinded the directive"
synonyms:   revoke, repeal, cancel, reverse, overturn, overrule, annul, nullify, void, invalidate, quash, abolish; More